# Reading an array in a function and printing it in main function

Tags: arrays, c

I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void readarr(int *array){
    int len;
    scanf_s("%d",&len);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d",&array[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    int array[100];
    readarr(array);
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",array[i]);
    }
}
```

The function readarr is of course supposed to read input from the user (the size of the array and then the elements) and the contents are supposed to be printed in the main function. However, for an input `3 1 2 3` this is what is printed:

```
123-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: How does `main` know how many elements to print?  You never provide that information.

Comment: I'm really stupid, thank you

Comment: @grokestray One option is to read `len` in main. This way you can check that `len` doesn't exceed the number of elements in `array` and you can use it in the loop that prints the data. Otherwise you should pass the array size to the function and (somehow) return the actual number of elements.

Comment: If the input is supposed to be a positive integer, you can add `arr[len] = -1;` at the end of `readarr()`. In this way `main()` doesn't need to know the length of the array, you can just do `for(int i=0;array[i]+1;i++)`. Where `array[i]+1` is equivalent to the condition `array[i] == -1`